# Formula Return Percentage Field Displaying wrong information

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula field (Utilisation %) which should return percentage. My formula is (Actual Time/Estimated Time *100).

Actual time (Number field) I am rolling up from time object from total hours field where I have removed decimal places. By default it is adding zero to the formula, resulting in wrong result.

Ex:

56/233*100=24.03% instead of this it is showing 56/233*100=2,403%
Actual time is taking 5600 while dividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to multiply by 100 in percentage formula fields.

For example, 0.4 will be displayed as 40%. In your case just removing the `*100` from your formula should do the job.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner If that's worked for you, could you please mark the Answer as accepted